# Could not determine whether value 7.3.1 is compatible with value 7.2.1 using AgpVersionCompatibilityRule

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, module

I moved an android code as a module for an app but im getting multiple errors which i have already configured for this here is my sample please have a look and give me better solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

and here is my code for app

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
    namespace "com.iw.tttttttt"
    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
        }
        applicationId "com.application.alphacapital.superapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
```

and here is for module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.incremental":"true"]
            }
        }
    }
```

Im expecting to any idea which fullfill my needs

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the namespace. On newer android versions, namespace is required to be declared on `build.gradle` explicitly. Like:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.myapp"
    ...
}
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace

And for the other issue, I don't think it's possible to tell what it is. You need to provide:

- `gradle-wrapper.properties`;
- `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"`;

So we can better understand the error.